# Selenium 3 - run recorded scenarios from python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/# and cannot find anything about running recorded Selenium scenarios from python. Is it possible?

If not, what is the best way to run recorded Selenium scenarios from CLI nowadays with Selenium 3?

I am using Selenium3.9.1, server-standalone is already downloads with all the dependencies, I have recorded and tested the scenario with Firefox plugin (it's stored by Selenium in a json file .side), just wondering how to run it from CLI? I hope I dont need to rewrite scenarios into python...

**Update**

I see there is something called Selenium Command Line runner https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/, will see if this answers my needs. Not python, but maybe I will wrap it with python...

Comment: The Selenium team close any feature requests for export in any other language than JavaScript and that feature is pending for a year now: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/131 - so no Python/Java/C# export with Selenium IDE 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can read .side(selenium ide) file and convert it to dict(it is allready in dict format)
and then using loop you can replay recorded steps in python